# Rx.NET TakeUntil example

Tags: system.reactive

The following [example](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/05_Filtering.html#SkipUntilTakeUntil)

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();
var otherSubject = new Subject<Unit>();
subject    
.SkipUntil(otherSubject)
.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
subject.OnNext(1);
subject.OnNext(2);
subject.OnNext(3);
otherSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
subject.OnNext(4);
subject.OnNext(5);
subject.OnNext(6);
subject.OnNext(7);
subject.OnNext(8);
subject.OnCompleted();
```

produces the output

```
4
5
6
7
completed
```

Shouldn't it emit the value 8 also? Why is it not emitting the value 8?

Comment: It should, and on my machine it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...brought to you by [the works on my machine certification program](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/)

[image: Courtesy of Jeff Atwood]